# Pivot table vs formulas Google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table, google-query-language

Just a quick question

Is it better to use pivot tables?

I would really appreciate if you can tell me why I should I usen them or why should I not.

Thanks!

Comment: they are slow...

Comment: Hey! @player0 

May you kindly elaborate a little bit pretty please? hehe

Comment: I personally never use them coz they are slow, bulky and user-hostile. if I need to pivot stuff I tend to use QUERY with pivot clause. ofc, everything depends on what job you require to do. and also there is always a chance that you will love them after you play with them more

Comment: Thats great! How do you use query with pivot clauses? May you provide me an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example:

```
=QUERY(A2:C; "select A,sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B")
```

[image]